# Does accurate translation estimation using a camera matrix mean the orientation estimation will also be accurate?

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, camera-pose, camera-calibration

Pose Estimation of single camera and planar pattern:

If I have an appropriate camera matrix with intrinsic parameters that allows me to calculate translation of the camera relative to a chessboard, for example, and it does so very accurately, does that mean my rotation calculations will also be accurate?

This may also be considered in the context of the [camera calibration documentation for opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

References to your answers would also be appreciated.

EDIT:
thanks to @tbirdal for the links
"Pose and position" is an incorrect phrase. Pose is a combination of position and orientation.

Comment: Please elaborate. Camera matrix doesn't represent your camera position but rather describes how it perceives the real world: projection. So in what context are you referring to that? Do you have a stereo or monocular setup?

Comment: @tbirdal, Edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pose estimation algorithm carefully minimizes the reprojection error using the standard non-linear techniques e.g., Levenberg Mardquardt, and your corner detection scheme is sufficiently accurate in the subpixel level, then yes. I would expect the residuals to be very small. Of course take into account the distortion parameters; they have to be calibrated as well. If you are using OpenCv and referring to the standard functions such as *findExtrinsicCameraParam*, then you are good to go.

The problem is also known as PnP due to the correspondences. Lepetit et. al. review it nicely [here](http://campar.in.tum.de/twiki/pub/Chair/TeachingWs09MATDCV/lepetit_ftcgv05-1.pdf).

Also, Grest et.al provide an overview of 3 methods [here](http://www.grest.org/publications/danielGrest_SCIA09.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the links, they proved very informative. Question was re-edited. Grest et.al showed that translation and rotation are very closely correlated when doing the estimations with all three methods. However when there is a deviation between translation and rotation, then translation would become erroneously estimated more easily than rotation. This answers my question.